# When to use 'config' level in logging

Tags: java, logging

```
public static void main(String[] arg)
{
     LOGGER.config("");
}
```

I visited many websites but i couldn't find an exact answer

Answer (score 2):

From the `java.util.logging.Level` Javadocs:

```
/**
 * CONFIG is a message level for static configuration messages.
 * <p>
 * CONFIG messages are intended to provide a variety of static
 * configuration information, to assist in debugging problems
 * that may be associated with particular configurations.
 * For example, CONFIG message might include the CPU type,
 * the graphics depth, the GUI look-and-feel, etc.
 * This level is initialized to <CODE>700</CODE>.
 */
public static final Level CONFIG = new Level("CONFIG", 700, defaultBundle);
```

In terms of severity it comes between INFO and FINE.